# Get Child Node Not Connected To Root Node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

[image]I have a binary tree that is broken and it has to be fixed by making sure all the childNodes can be traced or have their source from the rootNode. So for all childNodes, I want to get their root (which normally should be id:0)

Code to fetch every nodes in the binary tree.

```
FOREACH nodes
CHECK RELATIONSHIP IF ROOT PARENT ID NOT 0
```

ID 7 is detached from the root node, how do I run a check to know that 7, 9 and 10 are disconnected from the root node.

Comment: What are the labels and relationship types in your graph? And is your entire graph a single binary tree? If not, how are you supposed to identify nodes that are supposed to be part of the tree (so we can match on them and attempt to trace back to the root)? Also is there a quick way to match to the root?

Comment: The entire graph is a **Single Binary Tree**

This query gets all nodes from root to the last node

`MATCH (n:Tree {id:0})-[:PARENT_OF*..]->(c)`
`RETURN c LIMIT 100`

This query gets all nodes from childNodes to the root node

`MATCH (n:Tree {id:0})<-[:PARENT_OF*..]-(c)`
`RETURN c LIMIT 100`

Other childNodes are distinguished by their **id** while the rootNode's id is 0

Comment: You have two different directions for that same kind of relationship. I'm assuming the right direction is `(n:Tree {id:0})-[:PARENT_OF*..]->(c)`, with the direction outgoing from parents to child nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the situation, it may be quicker to match on root nodes, which should never have incoming :PARENT_OF relationships:

```
MATCH (root:Tree{id:0})
MATCH (falseRoot:Tree)
WHERE size((falseRoot)<-[:PARENT_OF]-()) = 0 and root <> falseRoot
RETURN falseRoot
```

From there you can find the other nodes connected to the disconnected false root node.

However, if there's a chance that your tree is broken in a way such that a loop is introduced, the above query may not detect it. This query should be able to:

```
MATCH (n:Tree)
WHERE (n)<-[:PARENT_OF*]-(n)
RETURN n
```

That will only get you nodes affected by the loop, you may need to look further up in the hierarchy to find the bad relationship, in this case.